# iOS: conflicting types for ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople

Tags: ios, objective-c, addressbook

I'm implementing a method to access the  framework.

but I'm getting this error:

> conflicting types for ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople

```
- (NSArray*) loadAddressBookContent:(ABAddressBookRef)addressBookRef
{
    NSArray *something;

    CFArrayRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef);
    CFIndex numberOfPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBookRef);
    return something;
}
```

any of you knows why I'm getting this error on this line:

```
CFArrayRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef);
```

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Update your question with the complete error message.

Comment: BTW - unless you need to support iOS 8, you should be using the newer Contacts framework.